# Best way to handle two factor authentication with node js

Tags: node.js, authentication, two-factor-authentication

I am planning to use AWS, node js, and react js for my application. The application should fulfill HIPAA compliance and DTAC. My first question is, is JWT best for authentication or should I use auth0? And the second question is, **what is the best way to handle two-factor authentication in node js**?

Answer (score 1):

As for your second question I noticed there is two ways:

1- Implement your own flow without using any third party service.
This can be done using TOTP algorithim usig one of node.js librarries and one of the most used is (speakeasy) but there is a lot others that implementing TOTP tokens.

2- Use third party provider such (auth0) they have an option to enable MFA.